# On an extension of Gauss Lucas

Tags: polynomials, convex-hulls

let $f(z)\in\mathbf{C}[z]$ be a nonzero polynomial. by the Gauss-Lucas theorem we have that $$\text{conv}(\{\text{roots of }f\})\subseteq\bigcap_{F'=f}\text{conv(\{roots of F\})}$$

**Question.** can the above inclusion be proper?

Example. suppose $f(z)=(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)$ has degree two and two distinct roots. pick an antiderivative $F'(z)=f(z)$ with $F(\alpha)=0$. then $\alpha$ is a double root of $F$ and so $F(z)=c(z-\alpha)^2(z-\gamma)$. by Gauss-Lucas, we know that $[\alpha,\beta]\subseteq [\alpha,\gamma]$. therefore $\gamma$ is on the ray from $\alpha$ to $\beta$. doing the same thing but replacing $\beta$ with $\alpha$, we get $G'=f$ with $\text{conv(\{root of G\})}=[\delta,\beta]$ for some $\delta$ on the ray from $\beta$ to $\alpha$. in total, the inclusion is an equality.

Comment: Can you add some context to this question? Specifically things you have tried, what the source of the problem is, et cetera. This will help us craft an answer in a way that will be most helpful to you.

Comment: the source is me, I guess someone else thought of it and proved it or disproved it. I succeeded proving it for $\deg f\le 2$, but the method does not generalize further.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to add a proof for $\deg f\leq 2$ (or at least a sketch) in the body of your question? I'd certainly be interested in seeing it.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut per your request, I added a sketch.

Comment: See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/58815).

Comment: @Maxim amazing! thanks